# Returning the last insert id in mysql is getting 0?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code to return the last insert id from the table employee kindly let me know what is wrong with the following code:

```
<?php 
$temp_array = mysql_query("select last_insert_id() from employee"); 
//now you can display it, to test it 
echo $temp_array;
?>
```

it return 0 value. Pls tell me the easy way to get this without using max(),

Comment: don't you have to do an insert before you can use last_insert_id()?

Comment: Yes i have inserted the new details...

Comment: what if you tried this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php?

Comment: Yes I tried the mysql_insert_id PHP function also. It also returning a 0.

Comment: You're lucky it returns anything at all, since the `mysql_query` function was removed from PHP 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) can be used to return the last ID generated for an auto increment column by the previous query (if the column is auto increment)

Answer (score 0):

$temp_array is of type Resource, rather than integer. You need to do

```
$rslt = mysql_fetch_array($temp_array);
$id = $rslt[0];
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php for details